# Climate in a really large canyon?

Tags: climate

**The idea**

I want to create a world/continent that includes several really large canyons (basically like valleys, but bordered by steep cliffs, not mountains). I'm flexible as to their depth, but looking at canyons on earth, I'd say they'd be several thousand meters deep. These are supposed to make up different counties of one state. There are also supposed to be other countries surrounding this country of canyons, on ground level (or above ground from the perspective of the valley-inhabitants).

**The question**

I realize that this would probably have some interesting effects on climate and daylight in the canyons, but I can't really figure out what exactly these effects would be. The most important question for now: Would there still be large differences in temperature between the canyons and the ground level, considering that the canyons are fairly large? If yes, what would some avarage temperatures be in, say, a canyon that's 5000 metres deep and the countries above that make human life possible in both of those regions? Would there also be big changes in climate between the center of a canyon and the areas close to the walls?

*Edit to clarify:* These "canyons" are supposed to have been created by a pretty big creature, not a river.

Comment: I hope this counts as one question - I'm new, so sorry if I got anything wrong!

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please remember that we have a strict limit to one question per post. Can you [edit] this post so that you're asking 1 specific question instead of the collection of questions that you are currently asking.

Comment: Calculating the amount of sunlight requires knowing not just the depth, but also the width, length, latitude and orientation of the canyons plus the axial tilt of the planet.  A canyon 5km deep that is 1m wide running north-south will get a very brief moment of sunlight once per day, a canyon 10km wide running east-west on the equator of a world with no axial tilt will receive practically the same sunlight as if it was not at the bottom of a canyon.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How **wide** are those valleys? Are they straight or crooked? How **long** are they? What is the climate in the surrounding area? Is there water flowing through the valleys? What is the altitude of the surrounding area?

Comment: Thanks Miluriel and welcome. This is many questions, actually. Please chop it up for us? I am voting to close for now, but it can be edited then reopened if that happens. Nothing personal! Questions you ask are: Would there still be large differences in temperature between the canyons and the ground level, considering that the canyons are fairly large? Would there be a temperature difference?  What would the avarage temperatures be a canyon that's 5000 metres deep? What about in the countries above? Would there be big changes in climate between the center and the walls? You see? Keep trying.

Comment: Similar [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/109146/what-sort-of-habitats-could-exist-pre-zanclean-flood-which-formed-the-mediterran) I asked awhile back based on the deep Mediterranean Valley before the Zanclean flood.

Comment: A canyon 5000 m deep excavated by some sort of animal? Doesn't sound remotely plausible to me.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I did sneak in quite a few questions! I think now that I have some general pointers I'll have to make some more decisions about the specifics before I try again.

Answer (score 3):

Would there be a temperature difference?  Very much so.

Here on Earth, the [adiabatic lapse rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate), the rate of temperature change with altitude, is about 9.8°C/km for dry air.  In a desert, your 5000-meter-deep canyon can expect the temperature at the bottom to be around 49°C higher than on the rim: if it's a warm 30°C at the bottom, the rim likely has snow; a cool 10°C on the rim is a scorching 60°C in the depths.

You can moderate this somewhat with moisture.  Wikipedia has [a chart of both wet and dry lapse rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Emagram.GIF); with high humidity, 30°C in the depths is around 10°C on the rim.

For a steep-sided canyon such as the Grand Canyon, there won't be much macro-climate difference between the edges and the middle.  The micro-climate will vary dramatically based on local topology such as shadowing or sun exposure.

Comment: Plus the increase in temperature [nearer the core](https://lisbdnet.com/what-is-the-temperature-distribution-with-depth-into-earth/), it gets pretty warm down there at a few km depth.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane, unless you're looking at a *really* narrow slot canyon, surface temperatures are dominated by the air temperature.  The ground doesn't conduct heat at all well, so the presence of rock at 150°C a few kilometers to the side of the canyon doesn't affect the ground temperature of the canyon to a measurable degree.

Comment: +1 for detail and I can add a small workout of the last sentence: micro-climate (very local) will depend on geography: the angle of the canyon in respect to the path of the sun. When these canyons are straight, a north-south canyon valley could become cold, because it won't see much sunlight in daytime That would be different for an east-west canyon ! In summer time, when the sun is up high in the sky, one side of the canyon valley could get more light than the other side, it will depend on the width of the canyon valley.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good starting point for more research! Also thanks for the mention of the angles of the canyon(s) having an effect - I didn't really consider that.